# Storing Time on chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Currently developing a chaincode and I have a doubt regarding storing dates.

If I have something like this:

```
result := XX{
    Timestamp: time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339Nano),
    ChangeSource: sourceOfChange,
}

stub.putState("result", result)
```

And  by having a consensus, will that work?

Will the `Timestamp` be equal between all the peers? Will this pass a consensus?

Comment: There is no guarantee and it is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not work reason is once the chaincode is executed the response is sent back to client where client evaluates whether all the responses are Same if they are different which in your case will be then the transactions are not sent for ordering

Comment: So to bypass this I can use something like this:
` 
timestamp,_ := stub.GetTxTimestamp()
Timestamp := time.Unix(timestamp.Seconds, int64(timestamp.Nanos)).String()
 `
?

Comment: You can, but the timestamp cannot be trusted, because it is sent by the user. You should additionally check that it doesn't deviate too far from the local time `time.Now()`.